# Scroll inactive window with keyboard

Tags: keyboard, windows, macos

It's well known that you can do this with the mouse wheel, but is there any option to do it with the keyboard?

I've been searching without luck. Neither in the Karabiner repo.

Comment: How are you going to indicate which window you mean? Whilst the mouse is in your hand, hovering the desired window seems pretty obvious, but then… you're right there & the mouse is in your hand.

Comment: @Tetsujin something like "get second frontmost application" given that the most common use case is to have it behind the current frontmost app. I see your point though

Comment: tbh, I'm more likely to want to scroll a window in another app entirely, but not necessarily its front-most window, I may have several spread around, across two screens. I have a browser with three conveniently staggered windows, each with many tabs… then I just need to lean over there & scroll my downloads, or photos, or a large text document, all of which I can see on the other half of my display… I currently have 9 different apps spread out, none of which hide any of the others, all neatly tessellated … which one? https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5hgt.jpg [intentionally too small to read]

Comment: @Tetsujin this got me thinking... My use case is to have a small terminal window in the lower right corner and read, for example, Stack Overflow or a pdf in a maximized window behind the terminal. This way I try snippets and do note taking. I would be very convenient for me to scroll this way the inactive window. I'll keep trying, this is kinda a "new necessity" to me. Thx